# Boolean algebra proof - point me in the right direction?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I wish to formulate a proof that if $x+y = x+z$ and $xy$ = $xz$ then $y=z$.  I'm just beginning my study of Boolean algebra, but is $y=z$ not self evident from the stated equations?

Comment: What happens if you add $x$ to both sides of the first equality ?

Comment: $x+x=x$ so both sides remain the same?

Comment: Does '$+$' stands for 'xor' or for 'or' in your definition?

Comment: Oh sorry, '+' stands for 'or'

Comment: Ok, my mistake then. From $x+y=x+z$ you can derive $(\neg x)y = (\neg x)z$ and then compute $(\neg x + x)y = \dots$.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.

Answer (score 2):

$x$ is either true or false. In either case you can derive $y=z$ from one of the equations.

Answer (score 0):

Use absorption and distributivity:
$$y=y(x+y)=y(x+z)=yx+yz=zx+yz=z(x+y)=z(x+z)=z.$$